# anypic facebook login error

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

so, i followed the guidelines that is introduced on anypic github page.
1. I put my pplication ID and client key in appdelegate.m
2. I made my app named 'app1'on both facebook and parse.
3. I put my facebook app ID in info.plist
4. i also wrote the URL scheme in info.plist
5. I put my facebook  app id and secret key in my parse account .
6.i also followed all the other changes  including cloud code, js and etc.
7. I also submitted my anypic's bundle identifier to facebook dashboard.
(which was com.parse.anypic)

However when i run the app on my simulator, whenever i press the facebook  button , the safari takes me to a web page saying 'the settings made by the developer is not proper to login(?)' well i'm not sure what this sentence actually means in english because i use different language on my virtual machine. Anyways if anyone knows anything about this problem please give me an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have made the Facebook app available to Public in your App Settings page.

Also You need to insert your platform details, for which platform you are developing your app and your development machine's keyhash. Make sure the key which you are using to debug your app is same whose keyhash value you enter on Facebook developer console.

Comment: You do not need a keyhash for iOS apps, this is Android only.